# How to access string resources of android from the ViewModel of core in Xamarin MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

- I have a array of messages defined in `strings.xml` in **`android`**
- How to access this array of messages from the `Core` part of `viewModel`
- Is this possible, If so how.

*Any Samples and documentation to know this*

Is `Event Handlers` are the only way to do this or is there a better way

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `strings.xml` from your Core assembly, because Xamarin accesses your string resources as properties in the Resource class within your Android project, and your Android project has a dependency on Core, not the other way around. I would consider setting the value of the string inside your `ViewModel`, and then binding your control to it's value instead of trying to retrieve it from `strings.xml`. That binding would look like this for a `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/your_control_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:MvxBind="Text YourTextProperty" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you project is multi-platform, you can [use resx to localize it](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/) (this link is for Xamarin.Forms but works well in regular apps too).

Otherwise, if you really want to use `strings.xml` you can use dependency injection to inject a "string provider" to your core project.